# How can i randomize background image on daily basis rather than everytime you refresh the page

Tags: javascript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  var images = [
    "d1.png",
    "d2.png",
    "d3.png",
    "d4.png",
    "d5.png",
    "d6.png",
    "d7.png",
    "d8.png",
    "d9.png",
    "d10.png",
  ];
  $("#bridge").css({
    "background-image":
      "url(images/slider/" +
      images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] +
      ")",
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a different result every time you call it. The current date however, only changes once a day. ;)

Comment: Looks like a good use case for using localStorage to store date and random value. Then update when date is different

Comment: Do you really want randomness? You could have something much simpler with something like "day of month modulo number of images" (`new Date().getDate() % 10`). The difference is that you'll get a sequetial, reproducible order that changes every day.

Comment: Thanks for your responses,

Comment: The reason why I randomize it is so that every user see's a different image. I created a scratch to reveal card and behind that card I have this random bg. My idea is to have the background image the same for every user for the day and the next day when they scratch to reveal they see a different image

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```js
const DAY = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var images = ['d1.png', 'd2.png', 'd3.png', 'd4.png','d5.png', 'd6.png', 'd7.png','d8.png', 'd9.png', 'd10.png'];
let currentDay = Math.floor(Date.now() / DAY);
let saved = localStorage.getItem('random_image');
if (saved) saved = JSON.parse(saved);
if (!saved || saved.day != currentDay) {
  saved = {
    day: currentDay,
    index: Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length),
  };
  localStorage.setItem('random_image', JSON.stringify(saved))
}
let image = images[saved.index];
console.log(image);
```

It uses LocalStorage to remember what the last randomly generated image was. If the day is different, it'll generate a new one.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried the code and it still randomize after refreshing

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is how the code looks like after adding the one above:  

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
const DAY = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var images = ['d1.png', 'd2.png', 'd3.png', 'd4.png','d5.png', 'd6.png', 'd7.png','d8.png', 'd9.png', 'd10.png'];
let currentDay = Math.floor(Date.now() / DAY);
let saved = localStorage.getItem('random_image');
if (saved) saved = JSON.parse(saved);
if (!saved || saved.day != currentDay) {
  saved = {
    day: currentDay,
    index: Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length),
  };
  localStorage.setItem('random_image', JSON.stringify(saved))
}
let image = images[saved.index];
console.log(image);

    $('#bridge').css({'background-image': 'url(images/slider/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
        }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: It's not really a good idea to re-post someone else's answer. If you need them to make improvements, you can suggest it in the comments.